# Cant inject classes using Dagger on Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am beggining with Dagger, I am using 1.2 version of it, and I have the following scenario:

Module:

```
@Module(injects = {
    AuthenticationService.class
})
public class ServiceModule {

    @Provides
    AuthenticationService provideAuthenticationService() {
        return ServiceFactory.buildService(AuthenticationService.class);
    }

}
```

On my Application class I create the ObjectGraph:

```
public class FoxyRastreabilidadeApplication extends Application {

     private static FoxyRastreabilidadeApplication singleton;

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         createObjectGraph();
         singleton = this;
     }

     private void createObjectGraph() {
        ObjectGraph.create(ServiceModule.class);
     }
}
```

and finally, at my LoginActivity, I try to inject my AuthenticationService:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    @Inject
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;
}
```

At this point, when I try to access my AuthenticationService instance it is always null, meaning it wasnt injected at all, I debugged my provider method to be sure of it, so, the question is, am I missing something? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold on to the `ObjectGraph` and ask it to inject your objects directly.

- Add an instance variable to your custom `Application` subclass to hold on to the created `ObjectGraph`:

`this.objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(ServiceModule.class);`

- Add a convenience method to your `Application` to do injection:

`public void inject(Object object) {
    this.objectGraph.inject(object);
}`

- Call that method wherever you need injection to happen, for example in your `Activity`:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((MyApplication)getApplication()).inject(this);
    ...
}`

Comment: Makes sense, I will try this soon, if it works I will gladly accept your answer, thanks for the reply :D